# Permutation module $M^\lambda$ as induced module

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

If we let $r$ be a natural number, $\lambda$ be a partition of $r$, $\Sigma_r$ be the symmetric group on $r$ numbers, we can define the following $K\left[ \Sigma_r \right]$-module:

$M^\lambda := \operatorname{span}_K \{\text{tabloids of shape } \lambda\}$. See for example G D James' Representation Theory of the Symmetric Group.

I've also seen that the module $M^\lambda$ can be defined as the induced representation of the trivial module over the Young Subgroup $\Sigma_\lambda := \Sigma_{\lambda_1} \times \Sigma_{\lambda_2} \times \ldots$ , for $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots)$, to $\Sigma_r$ i.e.:

$$M^\lambda = \operatorname{Ind}_{\Sigma_\lambda}^{\Sigma_r}(1),$$

where 1 denotes the trivial $K\left[\Sigma_\lambda\right]$-module.

I'm trying to prove that these two definitions give isomorphic modules, by finding a direct isomorphism or by proving that they are equivalent representations, but can't seem to generelize the basic examples I'm looking at.

If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it.
Note: I'm using the coset defintiion of the induced module, not the definition as the tensor product.

Comment: The coset definition should make this the easiest to check. You need to find an appropriate bijection between the $\Sigma_\lambda$-cosets in $\Sigma_r$ and the tabloids of shape $\lambda$. Try this: A permutation $\sigma \in \Sigma_r$ acts transitively on the tabloids of shape $\lambda$ by permuting their entries. So the $\Sigma_r$-set formed by the tabloids is isomorphic to $\Sigma_r$ modulo the stabilizer of any fixed tabloid. Now take the "superstandard" tabloid (i.e., the tabloid whose first row is $\left\{1, 2, \ldots, \lambda_1\right\}$, whose second row ...

Comment: ... is $\left\{ \lambda_1 + 1, \lambda_1 + 2, \ldots, \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 \right\}$, and so on), and find its stabilizer. Of course, once you have the bijection, you need to check that the $K$-linear map that lifts it is actually an isomorphism of $K\left[\Sigma_r\right]$-modules. But this is not difficult.

Comment: Amazing, I didn't think of looking at the stabilizers. Thanks so much! Do you know how I can mark this post as an answer?

Comment: Well, you can write an answer and accept it yourself, preferrably with more details than my brief sketch. :) I'll upvote it, just let me know.